# How do I iterate through and return each available hour of the day in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to query data about open appointment times from a practice management system and have read-only access. There is a column for blocked slots which represents time available for booking and a column for booked slots which represents whether the time has been booked or not. Every 5 minute interval in a 24 hour period is represented as a 0 or a 1. An available time would be represented by a 1 in the blocked slots column and a 0 in the booked slots column. What is the best way to iterate through this and return available date-times?

Thus far, I have tried creating case statements which return the time as the header and the value "OPEN" if the hour is available but I just need to return each date/time for each provider and location only if it is available.

Here is the code that currently returns Date, Location, Department, Resource, Blocked Slots, and Booked Slots:

```
    Select
      Cast(vwApptSchedAvail.Available_Date As datetime) As [Date],
      vwApptSchedAvail.Location As [Location],
      vwApptSchedAvail.Department As [Department],
      vwApptSchedAvail.Resource As [Resource],
      Available_Days.Blocked_Slots1 + Available_Days.Blocked_Slots2 As [Blocked Slots],
      Available_Days.Booked_Slots1 + Available_Days.Booked_Slots2 As [Booked Slots]
    From
      PM.vwApptSchedAvail vwApptSchedAvail Inner Join
      PM.Available_Days Available_Days On vwApptSchedAvail.Available_Date =
        Available_Days.Available_Date And vwApptSchedAvail.Resource_ID =
        Available_Days.Resource_ID And vwApptSchedAvail.Scheduling_Department_ID =
        Available_Days.Scheduling_Department_ID And
        vwApptSchedAvail.Scheduling_Location_ID =
        Available_Days.Scheduling_Location_ID
    Where
      vwApptSchedAvail.Available_Date Between '2019-10-23' And '2019-10-23' And
      vwApptSchedAvail.Location = 'Location A' And
      vwApptSchedAvail.Department = 'OP' And
      vwApptSchedAvail.Booking_Factor > 0
    Group By
      Cast(vwApptSchedAvail.Available_Date As date),
      vwApptSchedAvail.Location, vwApptSchedAvail.Department,
      vwApptSchedAvail.Resource,
      vwApptSchedAvail.Booking_Factor, Available_Days.Blocked_Slots1,
      Available_Days.Blocked_Slots2, Available_Days.Booked_Slots1,
      Available_Days.Booked_Slots2
```

My query returns something like this:

```
    +============+============+============+==============+==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+
    |    Date    |  Location  | Department |   Resource   |                                                                                                                                          Blocked Slots                                                                                                                                           |                                                                                                                                           Booked Slots                                                                                                                                           |
    +============+============+============+==============+==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+
    | 10/23/2019 | Location A | OP         |   Provider 1 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
    +------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 10/23/2019 | Location A | OP         |   Provider 2 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
    +------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 10/23/2019 | Location A | OP         |   Provider 3 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
    +------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 10/23/2019 | Location A | OP         |   Provider 4 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000222222222222111111112222111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
    +------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is how the data returned when I used case statements as mentioned above:

```
    +============+============+============+==============+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
    |    Date    |  Location  | Department |   Resource   | 0:00:00 | 1:00:00 | 2:00:00 | 3:00:00 | 4:00:00 | 5:00:00 | 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 14:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 18:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 20:00:00 | 21:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 23:00:00 |
    +============+============+============+==============+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
    | 10/23/2019 | Location A | OP         |   Provider 2 |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         | OPEN     |          |          |          |          | OPEN     |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
    +------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

That's better than the 0's and 1's but still not in the format I need.

I would ultimately like to be able to return something like this:

```
    +==================+============+============+==============+
    |    Date/Time     |  Location  | Department |   Resource   |
    +==================+============+============+==============+
    | 10/23/19 5:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 1 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 10/23/19 6:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 1 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 10/23/19 7:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 1 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 10/23/19 4:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 2 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 10/23/19 5:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 2 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 10/23/19 7:00 PM | Location A | OP         |   Provider 2 |
    +------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: OMG do you seriously store your data like that? That is a nightmare to work with. It violates 1NF by shoving a bunch of data into a single tuple. Updates and even queries from that are nothing short of horrific. If you fix your data model this becomes simple. You should only store data for when you have appointments.

Comment: Help me understand something here. By your explanation of the data you have times booked for Provider 1 between 8am and 3:55 pm. What happened to the first 8 hours of the day and the hour between 4pm and 5pm. Also, what about the hours after 7pm? There is quite a bit of information you have not shared about what you want here. I think you need to provide a [mcve]. I would also suggest using aliases that are shorter (or at least different) than the table names so you can easily decipher your queries.

Comment: @SeanLange, I didn't choose to store the data like that and never would if it were up to me. I am working with an actual practice management system, unfortunately. The first 8 hours of the day for Provider 1 are not available for scheduling as is represented by the series of zeroes in blocked slots. In booked slots, there are also zeroes for the same period indicating no appointments. From 8 - 4 p.m. there are ones which represents both availability for scheduling and that there are existing appointments.

Comment: Can you add a table with some sample data? Just 5 representive records... :)

Comment: @sxsn, like how the data is actually stored in the Available_Days table?

Comment: Oh I see. So the BlockedSlots is the data that is available to be booked. And BookedSlots is the time that actually is booked?

Comment: And of course your sample is not always 0 or 1. Look at Provider 4. You have several slots where the value is 2. And to be honest your desired output doesn't even come close to what you describe based on the sample data. There are many details missing in your explanation.

Comment: @SeanLange I tried to be as detailed as possible but you do bring up some good questions. You are correct that Blocked Slots is available to be booked and Booked Slots is time that actually is booked. I missed the fact that Provider 4 had a value of 2. That would indicate double-booking for the particular slot.

Comment: OK so can you provide what you expect as output for the sample data provided? You have several challenging pieces in this. You have to parse that big nasty string and then have to deal with a gaps and islands problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your sample data as text so we can easily make this consumable.

There are two major obstacles in the problem. The first problem is parsing that nightmare of a string into something usable. The easiest way to tackle this is with a tally table. I have created one here as a cte. Having a persistent indexed table should provide a slight performance benefit, but not that much. Using a tally table here is how I would tackle the first step.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ApptDate datetime
    , LocationA varchar(20)
    , OP char(2)
    , Provider varchar(20)
    , BlockedSlots varchar(500)
    , BookedSlots varchar(500)
)

insert @Something values
('10/23/2019'
    , 'Location A'
    , 'OP'
    , 'Provider 1'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
)
,('10/23/2019'
    , 'Location A'
    , 'OP'
    , 'Provider 2'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
)
,('10/23/2019'
    , 'Location A'
    , 'OP'
    , 'Provider 3'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
)
,('10/23/2019'
    , 'Location A'
    , 'OP'
    , 'Provider 4'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    , '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000222222222222111111112222111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
)

;
with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a cross join E1 b cross join E1 c), --this is enough for 1,000 rows. Way more than we need here
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select s.ApptDate
    , s.LocationA
    , s.OP
    , s.Provider
    , TimeIsBlocked = substring(s.BlockedSlots, t.N, 1)
    , BlockStartTime = dateadd(minute, 5 * (t.N - 1), ApptDate)
    , BlockEndTime = dateadd(minute, (5 * (t.N - 1)) + 5, ApptDate)
    , TimeIsBooked = substring(s.BookedSlots, t.N, 1)
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= 288 --the number of 5  minute time slots in a 24 hour period
order by s.Provider
    , t.N
```

This will return 288 rows per row of the sample data (your main query). One for each five minute time slot. It will also return the start and end time of that slot as well as if that time is blocked and/or booked. From here you will need to isolate the valid available time slots using the gaps and islands approach. This has been asked answered hundreds and hundreds of times. Hands down the best article discussing how to deal with this problem is from the late great Dwain Camps. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

First look at this parsing logic and understand what it is doing. Then take a shot at the gaps and islands piece of this. I can help with the final push if you need it but you will learn this technique a lot better if you figure it out. Be warned, this stuff isn't easy and not for the faint of heart. But the horrific architecture you are stuck with is making this kind of thing about a million time more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: If you are going to make the table with all time slots why not just join directly to it-- thus getting one row back (that is one row that succeeds in the join) for each marked 5 min increment?  Then with that result you can group by hour or whatever is needed.